# Why can't I clone any repository in Git?

Tags: git, macos, github

I use git all the time and for some reason now every time i clone ANY repo i get this error

```
 git clone https://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git
 Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/tamer /Desktop/paypal_adaptive/cancan/.git/
 error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
 https://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git/info/refs

   fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I doesnt matter what repo....public or private..is there a setting/file on my mac that i need to change to make this work again. BTW I am on a mac/snow leopard

Comment: Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: how do I update my version of git....i cant seem to find documentation on this

Comment: Then try upgrading your Git and see if the problem persists. The latest stable Git release is currently v1.7.6

Comment: There's a link to an installer at http://git-scm.com/.

Comment: do i need to uninstall my previous because i ran the installer from http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.5.4-x86_64-leopard.dmg&can=3&q= and it completed but i went into terminal and ran git --version and got git version 1.6.4.2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341221

> You can also try using the git protocol, instead of http.
>
> ```
> git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/e4/org.eclipse.orion.client.git
> ```
>
> http support was much improved in 1.7+ and that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

Comment: Applying this globally is a bad idea: it fixes this particular issue for quite a  high security concession. `git config http.sslVerify "false"` for a specific repo is the utmost I would do.